# How check if a Laravel Console Command Exists?

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I need to check if a Laravel Console Command exists and if it is in the protected command var to call them.

I need to call them from another Laravel console command. And I want to know if there are something like `exists_command('mycommand:foo')`

There are any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tested and working.

```
function command_exists($name)
{
    return array_has(\Artisan::all(), $name);
}

if (command_exists('config:cache')) {
    // success
}
```

Comment: In case someone wants to avail the same thing in Lumen without the facade, it should be `app(\Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class)->all()` I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Though @Sandeesh is right, we can check in this way:

```
function exists_command($name)
{
    return array_key_exists($name, \Artisan::all());
}

if (exists_command('mycommand:foo')) {
    // success
}
```

even in a shorter way,

```
function exists_command($name)
{
    return $this->getApplication()->has($name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
php artisan list
```

Will bring up all possible artisan commands. There is a 'command' subsection with your own created commands.

You would call them as follows

```
php artisan command:MyCreatedCommand
```

Edit: To check if a command exists in your project you can use php class_exists function

```
if(class_exists('App\Console\Commands\MyCommandName')){
  //Do whatever
 }
```

Comment: Ah okay, I understand. What version of laravel are you using?

Comment: I'm using Laravel 5.4

Comment: I need to search by command name, not by namespace. Thx for your help!

Comment: the command signature is a protected type so you will never be able to access it directly. This would be a neat feature though.